# Dúvida com criação de projetos no firebase

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, firebase

Eu tinha vários projetos no firebase e quando eu fui criar outro disparou essa mensagem: ***Faltam 3 projetos para atingir o limite***, mesmo eu dropando todos, que foi o que eu fiz e a mensagem continua, mas surgiu uma dúvida: Eu posso criar um projeto e adicionar nesse projeto vários aplicativos de diferentes tipos? Tipo: Crio esse projeto: **ProjetoMain** e nele eu incluo esses App's: **Autorizador, Agendamento, ComprasOnLine**, posso fazer isso? Acho que sim, porque o que vale é o **Server Key** e o **token** e esses estão relacionados ao **App** e não ao projeto, certo ou não?

Comment: Resposta curta: sim, sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Interessante o seguinte. Criei uma App dentro de um projeto existente, atribui meu Package Name e quando eu gerei o GoogleServices.json, o package name que estava era da outra App, a primeira e não dessa que acabei de criar.